# How to quickly concatenate char arrays?

Tags: c++

I'm implementing errors in my class. I mean I'm creating error messages for various misuses that might happen. I know how to combine strings and numbers though std::string or stringstream but I'm wondering if there is a shorter way to do it, heres an example from within the bracket operator:

```
std::stringstream err;
err << "The key " << key << " is not set.";
throw std::invalid_argument(err.str());
```

And I'm looking for something that would fit on one line sorta like this:

```
throw std::invalid_argument("The key " + key + " is not set."); <- obviously broken
```

Any format that the std::invalid_argument will take is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [*`std::to_string`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) <sup>***C++11***</sup>

```
throw std::invalid_argument("The key " + 
                             std::to_string( key ) + 
                            " is not set.");
```

Comment: Safety warning: instantiating an `std::string` can throw an exception.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, but this is independent of whether you construct the string as a named object before or as an unnamed temporary inside of the throw expression.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to create your own exception class with a constructor that takes a `uint64_t` and creates the error message by itself:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class MyException : public std::invalid_argument
{
private:
    static std::string GetMessage(uint64_t key)
    {
        std::ostringstream err;
        err << "The key " << key << " is not set.";
        return err.str();
    }
public:
    MyException(uint64_t key) :
        std::invalid_argument(GetMessage(key).c_str()) {}
    virtual ~MyException() throw() {}
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw MyException(123);
    }
    catch (std::exception const &exc)
    {
        std::cout << exc.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more appropriate to override `virtual char const * std::exception::what() const`, so the string processing occurs inside the `catch`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Why? String processing triggering an out-of-memory condition will be hard to manage other than with program termination in any case. I'd even say an environment which *really* lets you reasonably handle an out-of-memory error will typically outrule exceptions in the first place. And overriding `what` means that you have to cope with nasty lifetime issues (you cannot just return `err.str().c_str()`).

Comment: 1. Separation of concerns. Preserve the information and give the rest of the program a chance to benefit before it's serialized into a message. 2. At least the `MyException` will exist before the out-of-memory occurs. String processing failure in the constructor would preempt it completely. 3. You only need to add an empty `std::string` member (no dynamic allocation) and use it to cache `what()` to solve the lifetime issue.